# Delphi & Indy httpServer how stop sending 400 bad Request

Tags: delphi, indy, httpserver

I get data from a device that expects him back ACK (HTTP1/1 200 OK).
My httpserver after receiving header is automatically returned 400 Bad Request (i see on WareShark).
Perhaps the device is not properly built his request.
How do I stop server does not return an error? So I will be able to continue communication with device.

thanks

---

```
LOG: 192.168.1.141:57565 Stat Connected.

HTTP Connect 192.168.1.141
LOG: 192.168.1.141:57565 Recv 10.4.2017 г. 00:18:43: POST / HTTP/1.1<EOL>

LOG: 192.168.1.141:57565 Recv 10.4.2017 г. 00:18:43: Accept: image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/msword, application/x-shockwave-flash, text/*, */*<EOL>Accept-Language: en-us<EOL>Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded<EOL>Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate<EOL>User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705)<EOL>Content-Length: 579<EOL>Connection: Keep-Alive<EOL><EOL><?xml version="1.0"?><EOL><Metrics  SiteId="BG-001" Sitename="office Pazardjik"><EOL><Properties><EOL><MacAddress>00:b0:9d:7f:b7:b2</MacAddress><EOL><IpAddress>0.0.0.0</IpAddress><EOL><Timezone>2</Timezone><EOL><DST>1</DST><EOL><DeviceType>0</DeviceType><EOL><SerialNumber>8370098</SerialNumber><EOL></Properties><EOL><ReportData  Interval="1"><EOL><Report  Date="2017-04-06"><EOL><Object  Id="0" DeviceId="BG-001-01" Devicename="Main Entrance" ObjectType="0" Name="Main Entrance"><EOL><Count  StartTime="05:31:00" EndTime="05:32:00" Enters="0" Exits="0" Status="0"/><EOL></Object><EOL></Report><EOL></ReportData><EOL></Metrics><EOL>

HTTP Header 
Accept: image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/msword, application/x-shockwave-flash, text/*, */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705)
Content-Length: 579
Connection: Keep-Alive

LOG: 192.168.1.141:57565 Sent 10.4.2017 г. 00:18:43: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request<EOL>Connection: close<EOL>Content-Length: 0<EOL>Date: Sun, 09 Apr 2017 21:18:43 GMT<EOL><EOL>


LOG: 192.168.1.141:57565 Stat Disconnected.
LOG: 0.0.0.0:0 Stat Disconnected.
```

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Please [edit] your question to make it more clear for us to understand. I don't understand which side your HTTP server is on. Are you writing an HTTP server which a device connects to? Or is your code connecting to an HTTP server on a device? Where is your problematic code? Have you noticed the `Access Violation` errors in your log? Where did your log come from?

Comment: I create server to which the device connects. The problem is described in the question. My server returns an error to the device with which it stopped communicating with me.  Access Violation errors irrelevant here since I cut off another part of the code. LOG from idHttpServer.Intercept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The HTTP client is sending an HTTP 1.1 request, but is not sending a required `Host` request header. Per [RFC 2616 Section 14.23](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.23):

> **A client MUST include a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request messages**. If the requested URI does not include an Internet host name for the service being requested, then the Host header field MUST be given with an empty value. An HTTP/1.1 proxy MUST ensure that any request message it forwards does contain an appropriate Host header field that identifies the service being requested by the proxy. **All Internet-based HTTP/1.1 servers MUST respond with a 400 (Bad Request) status code to any HTTP/1.1 request message which lacks a Host header field**.

`TIdHTTPServer` returns a 400 response if it receives an HTTP 1.1 request without a `Host` header.  As you can see above, the 400 response is mandatory by the HTTP 1.1 spec.  I suggest you contact the device manufacturer and report a bug about the missing `Host` header, maybe they can release a firmware update.

In the meantime, you can use the `TIdHTTPServer.OnHeadersAvailable` event to insert a dummy `Host` header if it is missing:

```
procedure httpServerHeadersAvailable(AContext: TIdContext; const AUri: string; AHeaders: TIdHeaderList; var VContinueProcessing: Boolean);
begin
  if AHeaders.Values['Host'] = '' then
    AHeaders.Values['Host'] = 'myserver';
  VContinueProcessing := true;
end;
```

As for your log, it shows an Access Violation occurring in your `OnCommandGet` event handler, due to a nil pointer being accessed.  That event is not triggered in the case when the client `Host` header is missing.  So you clearly have a second issue in your code, not related to this issue.

Comment: Ok. I understand this, so I wrote that perhaps the device is not built a query correctly. The question is, Can I decide whether to return error, because it stops the device to communicate with me

Comment: Access Violation errors irrelevant here since I cut off another part of the code. When the device does not receive ACK then repeat your request. So I can not get all the data, just the same.

Comment: Thanks Remy. Even with my English understand the question and gave me the solution. I counted on you to give decision. The manufacturer has a new device that no such problem. But this is 2006 and probably then there was another specification  Best Regards

Comment: Hello again. After the correction has an error 400 is not released, but remains onCommandGet -> ARequestInfo.Poststream = nil. The interesting thing is that if I put VCanFree: = False in httpServerDoneWithPostStream then the Contents data arrive at the event httpServerCommandGet

Comment: @StoyanToskov: The `ARequestInfo.PostStream` holds the raw posted data. It gets reset to nil if `TIdHTTPServer` parses the data into other properties and no longer needs the `PostStream` anymore. This currently only happens if the client posts an `application/x-www-webform-urlencoded` submission, in which case `TIdHTTPServer` parses the data into the `ARequestInfo.FormParams` property and then discards the `PostStream`. If you want to keep the `PostStream` in memory until you have finished processing the request, then yes, set `VCanFree=False` in the `OnDoneWithPostStream` event.

Comment: Do exactly what is read in the header: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: My point is, `TIdHTTPServer` can automatically parse `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data for you, populating the `ARequestInfo.FormParams` and `ARequestInfo.Params` properties with the decoded values, so you usually don't need the `PostStream` itself for an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded data` request.

Comment: Yes I understood exactly where are my data and why is there. Thank you